# Sharing Ionic project for html and CSS editing

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

Is there an online platform or editor where I can share my Ionic project , so that someone can edit the HTML and CSS files but have no access to JavaScript back end code?

Whereby there is no need to install nodejs as the server would be performing the compile?

Comment: You can share the code via git and let the user install node and run the project

Answer (score 2):

You can share the code using [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) or [github](https://github.com/)

Comment: What about StackBlitz?

Comment: `StackBlitz` is an online IDE where you can create Angular & React projects that are immediately online & shareable via link… in just one click but `git` allow you to share and add your team members to the project and each one of them can push his/her edit to the `git` so everyone can pull it to their project in their desktop not online you can use whatever work with your requirement.